# Ручное задание id у записей в таблицах в postgresql

Tags: django, postgresql

Имеется форум phpbb3 с БД MySQL. В ней есть таблицы пользователей,сообщений и тем. В таблице есть id, на значении котором формируются ссылки следующего вида:

```
/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=7257
/viewtopic.php?p=121006
/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=2703
```

phpbb3 очень не удобен и архаичен, есть желание заменить другим форумом. Выбрал вариант на django, заодно решил сменить БД на postresql. Сейчас занимаюсь переносом данных в новую БД. Хотелось чтобы записи в postresql имели те же id, что и в mysql, поскольку опять те же ссылки на пользователей, темы и сообщения основаны на id, но уже в другой БД. При совпадении id будет гораздо проще делать переадресацию старых ссылок на новые, ну и ещё пару удобств.

1) Можно ли задавать первичный ключ вручную? Не вызовет ли это потом проблем с БД? И допустим я задам id 1, 2, 4. После этого какой номер будет у следующей создаваемой записи без указания ключа? Номер 3 или 5?

2) Можно ли и как вручную задать id средствами самого django? Сейчас пользователь создается как-то так, используется своя модель User c различными полями, но естественно без явного id.

```
new_user = User(...)
 ...
new_user.save(force_insert=True)
```

Спрашиваю, тк так с django проще добавлять записи, имеются уже готовые методы добавления, а с добавлением вручную записей sql запросом нужно заполнять большее количество полей, а так же боюсь что могу упустить некоторые моменты (подсчет счетчиков, статистики и прочего).

Answer (score 1):

очень много вопросов. Должно было толко 1

> 1) Можно ли задавать первичный ключ вручную? Не вызовет ли это потом
>   проблем с БД? И допустим я задам id 1, 2, 4. После этого какой номер
>   будет у следующей создаваемой записи без указания ключа? Номер 3 или
>   5?

*да можно без проблем*. Но для многопоточности используются `sequence` (последователь) который хранит одно числовое значение и дает следующее при вызове через `next_val()`

только учтите, если одновременно 2 пользователя будут обрашатся и вы не сможете это поставить на последовательность, ваши ID начнут конфликтовать.

Comment: Ну вопрос то по сути один, можно ли задавать id вручную и если можно, как это сделать средствами django. Сейчас нашел, как я понимаю, просто можно задать перед new_user.save `new_user.id = 5` и все?

Comment: @alff0x1f да так можно задавать

Answer (score 1):

1) Можно (а часто и нужно) задавать первичный ключ вручную.
2) Без указания ключа никакого ключа не будет. Будет null и как следствие шашлык из тебя будет.
Чтобы был ключ его надо:
а) задать вручную
б) использовать sequence в default value поля

```
CREATE SEQUENCE sequence_name;
CREATE TABLE table (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('sequence_name'),
    ...
```

в) использовать тип поля SERIAL

```
CREATE TABLE table (
    id SERIAL,
    ...
```

что в общем-то тоже самое, что вариант б) только с неявной последовательностью

`nextval` всегда возвращает следующий номер из последовательности.
Каждый вызов `nextval` возвращает новое число (если конечно перед этим вызовом не изменять последовательность вручную).

На практике часто поступают так.
В программе получают следующий id_value с помощью `SELECT nextval('sequence_name')`
Полученный таким образом id_value указывают вручную `INSERT INTO table (id, ...) VALUES (id_value, ...)`
Таким образом всегда будет известен id новой записи, не прибегая к каким-то хитростям. Его можно сразу же использовать для связи с другими таблицами.

Многие библиотеки/фреймворки и пр. именно так и работают. Просто им надо указать какое поле является ключом и какую последовательность для него использовать. Возможно и django так умеет, не знаю о нём абсолютно ничего.

Экспортируйте базу из MySQL в Postgres с оригинальными id.
Создайте sequence для id.
Установите текущее значение sequence равным максимальному id из базы + 1:
`SELECT setval('sequence_name', max_id + 1, false)`
Для генерации id новых записей используйте `nextval('sequence_name')`
`new_user.id = SELECT nextval('sequence_name')`